# Add new line within textbox and label from code behind c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, newline

Here is my code for creating the textbox and label from code

```
        int i = 0;
        Label lbl = new Label();
        lbl.Text = "Label - " + i.ToString();
        lbl.ID = "Label - " + i.ToString();

        TextBox txt = new TextBox();
        txt.Text = "txt - " + i.ToString();

        data.Controls.Add(lbl);
        data.Controls.Add(txt);
```

Is it possible I add a new line after the `data.Controls.Add(txt);`?

I tried to use `Environment.NewLine` but its not working.
anyone have any idea how to do it?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think that labels can't be multiline. But you can set your textbox to be multiline and then use *System.Environment.NewLine*.

Comment: @Robert you may be wrong! You can do it (only tested in WPF) with label.Content += "\n This is a new Line". So he is using asp.net and i have no experience in it - moreover in asp.net i assume that a label has no .Content so it would be label.Text += "\n new Line"

Comment: What is the data object you use here? The question is not about Label or TextBox, it is about the data object that we have no definition of.

Comment: Since it seems that you are a beginner in ASP.NET development, why do you start with dynamic controls at all? Use the aspx to declare your controls. You can control visiblity from codebehind if that's what you want. Maybe you want to use a web-databound control like `Repeater` or  `GridView` if you habe a loop. You can also use a `UserControl` if you want to wrap your two control in one. On that way you can reuse it wherever you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br/>"));
```

Add this for new line

Answer (score 0):

Add a Literal Control in between your two controls for line space.
Programatically you can do it.

Set Literal Control's `Mode` property to `PassThrough`
For Example :

```
Literal myLiteral = new Literal();
myLiteral.Id="lit_newline"
myLiteral.Mode = "PassThrough";
data.Controls.Add(myLiteral);
```

Then Add this control in between your textbox and label control

Also you can do like this

```
data.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));
```

And If you want, you can apply css to your textbox without adding the literal control which will increase the height - as answered by user : bgs264

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118316/how-can-i-add-a-line-break-or-html-inside-of-a-panel  and this   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/830304/hw-to-create-line-breaks-between-dynamically-generated-labels-in-a-placeholder

Comment: @srimanreddy: he has not copied your answer, he uses `<br />` and you `<br>`. He also posted one minute earlier.

Comment: also look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14463766/add-line-breaks-to-literal-controls

Answer (score 0):

You should use CSS if it's purely for presentation.

Add `.CssClass = "TextboxSpace"` to the textbox
Add a css file to the project (or add a new style to an existing one) something like

```
.TextboxSpace {
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you saying the space between the two controls.. If this is the case, you can set the location for the next control such that there is a empty space after that text.